# How to remove files from wrongly merged branch?

Tags: git, git-merge

I got two branches: master and ubuntu. Normally I merge master to 'ubuntu'. 'Ubuntu' branch contains master plus own '/debian' folder, which is not in the master. Due to mistake I merged 'ubuntu' to the master, and brought '/debian' folder to the master.

I want to remove it from the master, but I want to be able to merge master to ubuntu without damaging it own '/debian' folder when I would merge master to 'ubuntu' again.

How can I do this? Merge happened some time ago and there are tons of commits since than...

Comment: I assume you pushed these changes.  You might want to revert the commit and push again.

Comment: There are many commits after that. To make thing worse, there were few 'ubuntu'->'master' merges. Is any way to say to git 'those files are just disappeared', like they were never added/removed?

Comment: @George Shuklin Have you pushed your local/master to remote ?

Comment: @GeorgeShuklin Git never forgets  :)  You can rewrite history, but cannot forget the original.  My suggestion would be to do it manually now but looking into the problem commit from past.  It will be lesser pain.

Comment: @sajib khan, yes, I already pushed to remote.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can `reset local/master` and `replace remote/master history` by `local/master`.

1. At first find out the `last commit before merging ubuntu`. `git log` maybe good choice.

   ```
   $ git checkout master

   $ git log --since=1.hour.ago                      # commit-time < 1 hour
   $ git log --since=3.hour.ago --until=1.hour.ago   #  1 hour < commit-time < 3 hour
   $ git log --since=1.day.ago                       # commit-time < 1 day ago
   ```
2. Copy the `commit-sha` and do `hard-reset` your local-master to that commit:

   ```
   # backup master for safety
   $ git branch master.bac           # backup master to master.bac branch

   $ git reset --hard <commit-sha>
   $ git push -f origin master       # force push, replace remote/master history with local/master
   ```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not an option. force push is disallowed, and this is not the thing I want to do. I want some normal operation, not history rewrite.